# HTML5 Video Subtitles Styling

Tags: javascript, html, webvtt

Is it possible to apply styling to a HTML5 video player subtitle track element? I want to move the subtitles outside of the media player.

I have tried targeting the media player and the track element with css, neither have any effect.

If it's not possible, could I read the contents of the subtitles track element with jquery? I've tried reading the contents with .html() and .val() - neither work.

Comment: Checked this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video

Comment: According to that, the only css styles that can be applied are: 

    color,
    opacity,
    visibility,
    text-decoration,
    text-shadow,
    backgrounds,
    outline,
    font ,
    white-space...... 

Seems like it may not be possible to move the subtitles outside of the media player.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/icelab/jquery-videosub

That has allowed me to use a .srt subtitles file and display the contents in-time with the audio in a completely separate div that I can style.